# mysql event for selecting registration id

Tags: mysql

i need to insert reg_id of patient form first table (registration_table) to second table (patient_status) for those patient whose registration is done 30 days before

[image: table first (registration_table)]

[image: second table (patient_status)]

my query

```
INSERT INTO patient_status(reg_id) SELECT reg_id FROM  registration_table
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,reg_date,getdate()) >= 30
```

it says

Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: The [documentation on `DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is quite clear: **Two arguments** and two arguments only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateDIFF return the number of DAY so you need  simply  and in mysql you should use CURDATE() (getdate() should be from sql-server)

```
  INSERT INTO patient_status(reg_id) 
  SELECT reg_id FROM  registration_table
  WHERE  DATEDIFF(curdate(), reg_date ) >= 30
```

Answer (score -1):

you're supplying a third parameter to your DATEDIFF(start,end) function.